# 2 divs that "should" have equal height, but one appears to be a pixel larger than the other

Tags: css, html, layout, height

EDIT again:
They appear to look the same at certain zoom levels, but zooming in and out reveals the discrepancy. FF's default zoom makes them look incorrect, Chrome's default looks OK but the discrepancy is revealed after zooming in.

EDIT: here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eHRkb/

Here is the situation: My base "unit" is a 50px x 50px square.

I have a div that is 48x98 with a border of 1 for a total size of 50x100, so that is a 1x2.

I have a div that is 48x48 with a border of 1 for a total size of 50x50, so that is a 1x1.

I have a div that is 50x100 with 0 border, for a total size of 50x100. That is the 1x2 Container, intended to hold 2 1x1 divs.

I want to display two 1x1s on top of each other, and a 1x2 immediately to the right. This is achieved by putting the 2 1x1 divs into the container, and both the 1x2 and 1x2 container are `float:left`, so it should look like this:

```
|[X]||   |
|[X]||   |
```

**The problem I am having is that the left div, the container, appears to be 1 pixel shorter than the div on the right.** They are both 100px in height, including borders, so I am not sure what is wrong, since their heights should be identical, right? Below is my CSS and HTML.

**CSS**

```
.tile1x1
{
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    float:left;
}

.tile1x2
{
    width:48px;
    height:98px;
    float:left;
}

.tile1x2Container
{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    border:none;
}

.border1
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tile1x2Container">
<div class="tile1x1 border1"></div>
<div class="tile1x1 border1"></div>
</div>
<div class="tile1x2 border1"></div>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: put your code on Jsfiddle, so that we can help u better.

Comment: It seems like they line up so I don't see what the problem is. Perhaps check the rest of your css for a conflicting class.

Comment: i guess u need to put outline also to none or 0px and give a try .. doesnt seem to be different in any case in the above example

Comment: Wow, OK so after looking further, they line up for me in Chrome but not FF 25, can anyone else replicate that? Viewing the same fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/f74yT/) in both browsers.

Comment: Sorry that is not completely accurate. They appear OK at some zoom levels. @jonahfree please go back to the fiddle and zoom in and out. I can replicate the behavior in chrome and FF now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the box-sizing property to make it fit.  To do this, we need to make a couple changes.

.tile1x1Thumb should have a height of 49px not 48px.

Now add the following into .border1:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHRkb/1/

**Documentation**
[box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: I see that this does solve my problem but I don't understand, here is my reasoning which led to my issue, please correct the part that I have wrong: Left side: each square, height of 48, + border of 1 =50, 2 of those stacked on top of each other=100px. Right side: 1 div, height 98 + border of 1=height 100. So which of those assertions is wrong, and how does your change correct it?

Comment: Also, this creates another issue: I have a similar setup for horizontals: when I have 2 squares next to each other on top of a horizonal rectangle, those used to look fine, but now with your fix the 2 squares are slightly skinnier than the rectangle

Comment: I had the same problem before and had the same reasoning.  What box-sizing does, it places the border inside and forces the browser to render it with the specified height/width.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp.  However, I don't know why the usual method fails.

Comment: I just read about box sizing. I had no idea you could change that behavior in CSS. This will save loads of time in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a rounding error caused by the zoom.

You have, at 1:1 zoom 50 + 50 = 100.

Now if you have say, a 5:3 zoom you get 83.33 + 83.33 = 166.66

when you round these to actual pixels, that becomes 83 + 83 = 167 and you have a 1 pixel discrepancy.